# Is it possible for RapidMiner to mine 50,000 documents using 4GB RAM?

Tags: text-mining, rapidminer

I am facing a challenge to process 50k rows of data with feedback in text form and I am trying to find a good way to reduce the dimensions. so far i have used the text processing steps - tokenize- transform to low cases- remove stop words and stem but it is still giving a very big dimension space of about 15,000 with words that have no meaning included as well. What else can I do to extract only the relevant words?

Comment: i am using 4GB RAM

Comment: Did you try pruning?

Comment: yes i did but with pruning it may remove words that are useful for the model. i have also tried using the wordnet dictionary function to just keen useful words with meaning but it was too much a load on my RAM to process it